# CSS background prolongment in input

Tags: html, css

I have a `background-image` for my `body` element.
I have put `input` buttons, and I would like them to have the same `background` as my `body` element in a prolongation (not setting the `background` again).
Is there a way to do that with CSS3 ?

**Code:**

```
body{
    background-image: url("images/fond.jpg");
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

.input-button{
 /* Code here */
}
```

Comment: `background-color: transparent;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set `background:transparent`

```css
body {
  background: url("//lorempixel.com/1600/900") no-repeat 0 0 / 100% auto;
}
.input-button {
  background: transparent;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0
}
```

```html
<input class="input-button" type="text" placeholder="I'm a input" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I tryed background: none; but it hadn't work. I was searching for something complicate when the answer is finally so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
body{
    background-image: url("images/fond.jpg");
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

.input-button{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```